# How to pass callback to init function in a class

Tags: javascript, callback

As I mentioned in the title, I would like to pass some function as a callback to init function in some class

I will put here some basic structure:

```
class Person {

  constructor() {
    this.nums = [1, 2, 3];
    this.init();
  }
  init() {
    this.nums.forEach(num => {
      console.log(num);
    });
  }
}
```

Let's say I would like to add this function as a callback to the init function:

```
function test() {
  console.log('test')
}
```

How can i do this

Comment: If `test` does not get an argument, it is useless. Please make your question more concrete, with concrete code acting on the concrete instance. It is hard to tell now why you would want this.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp

Comment: Does the OP  want to have the callback invoked as if it was a method of the `Person` instance?

Comment: @ProteinDev ... From all the provided solutions/approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @ProteinDev ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case the OP wants to have the callback invoked as if it was a method of the Person instance and in addition also wants to handle the passing of arguments to such a callback then `init` is not anymore just an initializer.

It turns into a single generic method of any `Person` instance which does invoke any passed function within such an instance' context while passing the rest of its arguments to the callback.

Such a method then might be renamed from `init` to `execute` ...

```js
function pushNumberValues(...values) {
  this.nums.push(...(values.flat()));
}
function logInstanceNumbers() {
  this.nums.forEach(num =>
    console.log(num)
  );
}

class Person {
  constructor() {  
    this.nums = [0, 1, 2];
  }
  execute(callback, ...args) {
    return callback.apply(this, args);
  }
}
const person = new Person;

person.execute(pushNumberValues, 3, 4, 5, 6);
person.execute(pushNumberValues, [7 , 8 , 9]);

person.execute(logInstanceNumbers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Person {
  constructor(cb) {
    this.nums = [1, 2, 3];
    this.cb = cb;
    this.init()
  }
  init() {
    this.nums.forEach(num => {
      console.log(num)
    })
    this.cb()
  }
}

const test = () => {
  console.log('test')
}

const myPerson = new Person(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `callback` as a parameter in your `init` method, & call the `callback` at the end of your `init` method.

While calling your `init` method, pass `test` as an argument.